# Accidentally added yeast in first 24 hours

Tags: yeast, wine

I am making plum wine.  The recipe said mash the fruit, cover with water, add a campden tablet and pectinase and leave for 24 hours before adding other ingredients.  I through the yeast in at the same time before I realized I needed to wait 24 hours.  Will this negatively impact on the rest of the process?

Answer (score 3):

The Campden probably will not kill your yeast, but will only make the yeast upset, causing them to increase sulfur production and make them more sluggish, but things will stabilize again after a week or so.  I believe everything will still turn out alright.  If you are concerned, then add extra yeast.  However I don't believe this will be necessary.  Good luck and enjoy.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to toss in extra yeast though. IMO.  As long as the original pitch wasn't huge.